Is it possible to use a Docker container as a build node without using the Jenkins agent?
I am trying to use an RHEL 5 Docker container to run Jenkins jobs, but RHEL 5 does not support anything more recent than Java 8. Is there a way to run a Jenkins job in this container without using the Jenkins agent to communicate to the Jenkins server? Maybe with SSH?
(Don't ask me why RHEL 5, it just is. I can't change it.)

This seems odd. You have some arbitrary RHEL5 container running and you want to run a job on it? What does the Jenkins server run on? Bare metal? VM? Docker? Jenkins can spawn docker containers to run build jobs.

The Jenkins server runs on a VM. Jenkins can spawn docker containers through various plugins, that's grade-school stuff, but I need to know if Jenkins can talk to those containers and submit the jobs via SSH and not force it to run the Jenkins agent.

I figured it out using a declarative pipeline and the docker object. No agent or Java needed. This simple demonstration pipeline works with an RHEL 5.11 container and Jenkins 2.452.1.
pipeline
{
  agent any
  stages
  {
    stage('One')
    {
        steps
        {
            script
            {
                docker.image('rhel5:latest').inside
                {
                    sh "cat /etc/redhat-release"
                    sh "echo 'Done!'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

